# How do I create a std::filesystem::exists() compatible path from a Windows::Storage::StorageFile?

Tags: c++, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I am using a FileOpenPicker to get a file (StorageFile^) in a Windows Universal App. That seems to work fine, and if I output the `StorageFile->Path->Data()`, it returns the expected file path (C:...\MyFile.txt).

When I try to open it and dump the contents to a string things go wrong (the string receives nothing), so as the first step, I was trying to verify the file path with `std::filesystem::exists()`.

To snip it down to the relevant bit:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(StorageFile^ InFile)
{
    std::filesystem::path FilePath = InFile->Path->Data();

    if (std::filesystem::exists(FilePath))
    {
        //Do things
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7780A842 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x039BC480.
Unhandled exception at 0x7AACF2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in MyApp.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

Seemingly, the path I attempt to pass into std::filesystem::exists() is invalid.

Any help pointing out where I am going wrong would be very appreciated!

This question had originally been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529094/string-conversion-from-systemstring-to-const-wchar-t) however that solution does not seem to work as it requires CLI(?) whilst I *think* I am using WinRT (however I can not find where in my project or settings to check that beyond having winrt available in includes).

Comment: Your code is using C++/CX or C++/CLI, not C++/WinRT (which indeed would qualify as C++, unlike the others).

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, how do I see which I am using in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: If the [/clr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation) compiler option is set, you're using C++/CLI. If the [/ZW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zw-windows-runtime-compilation) compiler option is set, you're using C++/CX. Otherwise you're using C++. Though it is alarming that you have to ask which programming language you are using.

Comment: @IInspectable Whilst I appreciate the help, the shade isn't too helpful. So far as I'm aware, the language I am using is C++.
Is this the "Consume Windows Runtime Extention" option that I'm seeing the "/ZW"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key things to remember about `StorageFile` in the Windows Runtime (using C++/CX or C++/WinRT) is that (a) it's not necessarily a file on disk, and (b) even if it is a file on disk you don't necessary have permissions to open it directly.

The only 'generally safe' pattern you can use for doing traditional file I/O operations on the `StorageFile` instance you are given by the UWP FilePicker is to create a temp directory copy from it and then parse the temp copy:

### C++/CX

```
#include <ppltasks.h>
using namespace concurrency;

using Windows::Storage;
using Windows::Storage::Pickers;

auto openPicker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker->ViewMode = PickerViewMode::Thumbnail; 
openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary; 
openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".dds"); 

create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([](StorageFile^ file)
{
    if (file)
    {
        auto tempFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder;
        create_task(file->CopyAsync(tempFolder, file->Name, NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName)).then([](StorageFile^ tempFile)
        {
            if (tempFile)
            {
                std::filesystem::path FilePath = tempFile->Path->Data();
...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

### C++/WinRT

```cpp
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h"

using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers;

FileOpenPicker openPicker;
openPicker.ViewMode(PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary);
openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".dds");

auto file = co_await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file)
{
    auto tempFolder = ApplicationData::Current().TemporaryFolder();
    auto tempFile = co_await file.CopyAsync(tempFolder, file.Name(), NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName);
    if (tempFile)
    {
        std::filesystem::path FilePath = tempFile.Path().c_str();
...
    }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: Thank you, Chuck. Using the temporary file certainly solves my explicit question, and  seemingly the underlying problem for good measure. So presumably I was attempting to use a file which the application did not have permission to open (as in this case, the file definitely was on disk)?  Thanks again!